# How do I automatically run a Maven configuration when I save a Java file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, compilation, maven-3, eclipse-mars

I’m using Eclipse Mars on Mac El Capitan.  I have a multi-module Maven project, where each module is loaded into Eclipse as a Maven-Eclipse project.  My question is, if I change a Java file and save it, how do I then automatically launch an action in Eclipse that will run a Maven goal?  My objective is to run a certain Maven configuration (mvn —file ../pom.xml clean package -DskipTests) every time I make a Java change.

Note that I do have the Project -> Build Automatically checked but I don’t think this has any tie in to Maven.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Save Hook Eclipse Plug in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/save-hook-eclipse-plug):

> *This plug-in listen for save action. If a save event is fired in the workspace, the plug-in search for a configuration file in each project. If found it will execute the specified java class or external program. The code is allowed to modify project files too. Useful to trigger some command on save, like code generation, resource sync, enhancement, deploy and so on.*

For creating an own *Save Action* hook see [*hook to save action in eclipse plugin*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851280/hook-to-save-action-in-eclipse-plugin).