# How to automatically call an external program on eclipse upon certain actions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I need to call a local script everytime I create a new file in a couple of my eclipse pdt projects (running eclipse Neon.2), is it possible to do so automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to create Eclipse Menu Hooks (*It'll be tricky and not 100% sure how ?*). See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/380457/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851280/hook-to-save-action-in-eclipse-plugin).

Easier way could be to write a simple application which will detect new files in a folder and executes actions instead of playing with Eclipse.